# state equation from given signal flow graph

Tags: signal, control-system, graph, state-space

I was solving a question in which I have to write state equations  from  given signal flow graph ,but I wanted to clear some basic doubts regarding general problem like this

I thought it can we solve by two methods

1.by converting given SFG into transfer function using Mason's rule and then converting transfer function into State equation

2. Write state equation directly (by observation) from given SFG

So my question

Is second method works always or it is unreliable in complex systems and we have to stick with 1st method although sometimes it is lengthy?

Or

there are some methods (other than method 1  that I mentioned) by  which we can directly Write state equations even for complex SFG?